# Codeigniter / JSON - array result invalid

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter, underscore.js

I have a strange behaviour in my code.

Underscore template:

```
    <% _.each(pinnwand, function(item,key,list) { %>
        <strong>Item: <%= item.name %></strong>
    <% }); %>
    <% _.each(pinnwand2, function(item,key,list) { %>
        <strong>Item: <%= item.name %></strong>
    <% }); %>
```

for the array "pinnwand" and "pinnwand2".

Arrays:

```
function getPinnwandData() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $array = $this->Pinnwand_model->getAllPinnwand($this->input->post('user_id'),"json");
    $data['pinnwand'] = array();
    foreach($array as $a) {
        $data['pinnwand'][] = array("name" => strtolower($a['name']), "id" => $a['id']);
    }
    $data['pinnwand2'] = array(array('name' => 'MettWand',"id" => 1),array('name' => 'wurst2',"id" => 2));
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Strange thing is, "pinnwand2" is displaying and "pinnwand" not.
Console log shows this:

```
Object {pinnwand: Array[0], pinnwand2: Array[2]}
```

and there are definitely some records in the database for "pinnwand".

this is the "Postman" json output:

```
{
"pinnwand": [
    {
        "name": "wurst wand",
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "schinken wand",
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "mett wand ",
        "id": "3"
    }
],
"pinnwand2": [
    {
        "name": "MettWand",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "wurst2",
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

}

what am I missing?! Thanks!

EDIT:
getAllPinnwand method:

```
    function getAllPinnwand($userId, $main = "all") {
    if($main == "json") {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('pinnwand', array('user_id' => $userId));
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('pinnwand', array('user_id' => $userId));
        $result = $query->result();
        foreach($result as $r) {
            $query1 = $this->db->get_where('pinnwand_content', array('pinnwand_id' => $r->id));
            $r->content  = $query1->result();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

change:

```
foreach($array as $a)
{
    $data['pinnwand'][] = array("name" => strtolower($a['name']), "id" => $a['id']);
}
```

to:

```
$csx = count($myarray)

for($x=0;$x<count($myarray);$x++)
{
    $data['pinnwand'][$x] = array("name" => strtolower($myarray[$x]['name']),"id"=>$myarray[$x]['id']);
}
```

Don't use reserved keywords like $array in code, just take other names. Don't expect that PHP is creating new elements. Just let the loop define the counter!

Look if that works....

Comment: still the same... pinnwand is empty, pinnwand2 has items

Comment: $array is perfectly safe

Comment: Can you please provide more code beside this snippet ?!
From the creation of this array to the xhr request with the expected result. Then we can help you. 

But only these few lines won't help us much to find the source of the problem.